# Trimming Blank Spaces in Char Column in DB2

Tags: casting, db2, trim

I'm trying to remove blank spaces that appear in a CHAR column within DB2. I received some helped here with the function `TRANSLATE` to determine if `Left` contained records that began with three letters:

```
select pat.f1, hos.hpid, hos.hpcd
from patall3 pat
join hospidl1 hos on pat.f1=hos.hpacct
where TRANSLATE( 
LEFT( hos.hpid, 3 ),
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 ) <> 'AAA'
order by pat.f1;
```

But as you can see in my screenshot, there are records that remain, presumably because they begin with a blank space. I tried `cast (hos.hpid as varchar)` but that doesn't work. Is it possible to trim these blank spaces?

[image: Record Example]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LTRIM() or TRIM() to trim blanks before the LEFT()

```
select pat.f1, hos.hpid, hos.hpcd
from patall3 pat
join hospidl1 hos on pat.f1=hos.hpacct
where TRANSLATE( 
LEFT( LTRIM(hos.hpid), 3 ),
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 ) <> 'AAA'
order by pat.f1;
```

Note that the use of such functions in the WHERE clause means that performance is going to take a hit.  At minimum, the query engine will have to do a full index scan; it may do a full table scan.

If this is a one time thing or a small table, it's not a big deal.  But if you need to do this often on a big table look to see if your platform and version of DB2 supports expressions in indexes...

```
create index myindex on hospidl1 
  ( TRANSLATE( 
LEFT( TRIM(hpid), 3 ),
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why, but I had attempted RTRIM first... Ugh.  But thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of db2, you can also use just trim() to remove blanks from both sides.

Comment: Note if all you need is the blanks removed from the left then use LTRIM() as that will be less overhead than TRIM().  Same applies to blanks on the right; you'd want to use RTRIM() instead of TRIM().  Only use TRIM() if you really need blanks from both sides removed.