# DB2 TRIM 000000 to 0

Tags: sql, db2

I have looked at:

- [DB2 SQL Query Trim inside trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774547/db2-sql-query-trim-inside-trim)
- [Trimming Blank Spaces in Char Column in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697838/trimming-blank-spaces-in-char-column-in-db2/28698540#28698540)
- [SQL Trim after final semi colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684520/sql-trim-after-final-semi-colon)
- The IBM infocenter.

I have a column that is six long and a character column.  A typical value would be AA01AA.  I need to substring the middle 2 characters out of the value and convert to a number.

I am doing this with the following code: `TRIM(L '0' FROM(SUBSTRING(Myfield, 3, 2)))`.  In the example value above that gives me 1.  The problem comes in when the value is 000000.  The trim returns ''.  I need it to return 0.

I have tried `REPLACE(TRIM(L '0' FROM(SUBSTRING(Myfield, 3, 2))),'' ,'0')` but that simply gives me a blank string back.  I have also tried `TRANSLATE(TRIM(L '0' FROM(SUBSTRING(Myfield, 3, 2))), '0', '')` but that gives an error about parameter 03 being an invalid data type, length etc.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
integer(substr(myField,3,2)))
```

The `SUBSTR` extracts the two characters, the `INTEGER` takes it as input and converts it to a number. `TRIM` is not necessary at all.

```
values(integer(substr('000000',3,2)))

1          
-----------
          0

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help.